# MATLAB - Numerical integration over non-simply connected domain

Tags: matlab

In Matlab's PDEtool I want to define a boundary condition which involves the integral of the solution over the whole domain.

To do that, one has to use a function handle to define coefficients of the Dirichlet boundary conditions ([see here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/steps-to-specify-a-boundary-conditions-object.html#buftxz0-1)).
Such function (in the documentation the function handle is called `@myrfunc`) would be the one which returns the integral the solution `state` over the domain, given that the solution is only evaluated on  a 2D mesh with points `region.x` and `region.y`.
My problem is that the domain is not rectangular, nor simply connected (and of course the mesh is not regular).

Any idea?